# Exporting Objects in NodeJS for API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api

I'm trying to write a RESTful API in NodeJS that connects to a MySQL database.  I have multiple files that handle routes:

[image: file structure]

I'm using the "mysql" package from www.npmjs.com.  In app.js I create a connection object for the database but then want to use that object in both books.js and entries.js.  I need to use the connection object to send queries to the database and I plan to do that in the routes files (books.js, etc.).  What is the proper way to export and import that object?  I'm new to NodeJS.  Also, app.js is already exporting "app".

app.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const bookRoutes = require('./api/routes/books');
const entryRoutes = require('./api/routes/entries');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'rlreader',
    password: process.env.MYSQL_DB_PW,
    database: 'books'
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

// Routes which should handle requests
app.use('/books', bookRoutes);
app.use('/entries', entryRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => { //request, response, next
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

books.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    axios.get('/').then(docs => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "hello": "hi"
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: create a `db.js` somewhere in your project, in which you `require('mysql')` and handle DB connection. Then you include it anywhre you want this way: `var sql = require('./db.js');` obviously path must reflect the script location. This tutorial could be useful https://www.codementor.io/julieisip/learn-rest-api-using-express-js-and-mysql-db-ldflyx8g2

Answer (score 0):

GrafiCode had the answer to this one. I made a separate file called db.js

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'rlreader',
    password: process.env.MYSQL_DB_PW,
    database: 'books'
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Then, in books.js I added:

```js
const con = require('../../db');
```

Then I was able to use the .query() from the mysql component in multiple files.